# WSO2 ESB won't start and won't say why

Tags: wso2, startup, esb

I'm stuck on a problem with WSO2 ESB that I can't figure out and believe...

I've installed localy an ESB for testing my implementation. I added in my installation dir in the component library a custom mediator. I restarted the esb everything was fine but I had an error in my mediator. I stopped the ESB and wanted to start it again. No errors, no logs nothing just those informations in the logs:

```
C:\Tools\esb\wso2esb-5.0.0\bin>wso2server.bat
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jre8
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Tools\WSO2ES~1.0\bin\..
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.wso2.securevault.commons.MiscellaneousUtil).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

After a while searching what could have happend I removed the jar. Same behavior. I created a brand new installation and started it -> same behavior.

I feel kind of lost as there's no logs, no errors, no timeout, nothing just those 5 lines of logs... Please help me!

ESB Version 5.0.0

Thanks and cheers,
Frédéric

Comment: I've seen the same question on SO many times before. Sometimes the reason was a space character in the path of WSO2_HOME. But it looks like we can ignore that in your case. Can you extract a new pack **to a different location** and see if it's the same?

Comment: I actually tried it both on my client laptop and work laptop, on both I had a functionnal installation of WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 that I already used for many examples. And on both after adding this new jar I had the same error messages coming even after a new installation of the ESB. I must say I add in the compilated Jar the next dependency: <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
<artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
<version>2.1.7-wso2v7</version>

Comment: Without this dependency I had no problem with the jar but he couldn't find the AbstractMediator class as first I putted the dependency has "provided". Then I though ok AbstractMediator is not in the ESB library I've to add it and then the error appeared...

Comment: I could start again my ESB, the jar was copied by the ESB into the dropin folder actually. I still don't understand why with a new installation the problem still appeared but I maybe confused some directory or wathever. Still the problem remains with the log error as soon as I had the dependency synapse-core into my jar. I will continue to analyze.

Comment: I'm starting to ask myself if I didn't do anything wrong in my pom file. It seem that wso2 ESB 5.0.0 work with Java version 1.5:  https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Writing+a+WSO2+ESB+Mediator in the pom file they use this version for the compilation and I use java 1.8, and the 2.1.7-wso2v7 version, should I revert to 1.5?

Comment: 1.5 is from old docs, which is wrong now. 1.7 and 1.8 should work.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a part of an answer. Or at least I've a theory:
I setted in the lib directory my jar-with-dependencies => we should add only the compilated jar file without dependency and add external dependencies manually aswell in the lib folder! I had a Junit library in my jar-with-dependency therefore I became this log4j error probably.

For the problem with the new installation, somehow when you have started your esb inside a console in windows and you don't close it and switch to a new installation folder it still start the old installation instead of the new one. Therefore I though that the errors where still coming or something like this, probably because the JVM wasn't shutdown correctly. or at least it's what I expect!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your CARBON_HOME should be C:\Tools\WSO2ES~1.0\ (without bin in the path).
Not sure if this can be the only reason.

Comment: You'are right but it is look at the CARBON_HOME directory it's referenced like this C:\Tools\WSO2ES...\bin\.. => the .. means that it goes one directory backward ;)